# p.d.f Notation: Are $f_{x|y}(x|y)$ and $f_{x|y}(x)$ the same?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation, terminology, conditional-probability

I've been reading different textbooks and I'm so confused by the notation of conditional probability density functions(p.d.f's).

Please correct my understandings below.

**Setting**:
First of all, we use $\omega$ to denote the elements in the sample space of one experiment, use $\mu$ to denote the elements in the sample space of anther experiment. We assign random variables X and Y respectively to these experiments.

**Understanding**:

The subscription of p.d.f refers to the corresponding random variable.

Say, $f_x$ is the p.d.f of random variable X, namely the derivative of $F(X(\omega)\leq x)$ on all values of x. Following the pattern, I would say $f_{x|y}(x|y)$ is still a p.d.f on X, but the difference is that it's calculated by taking derivative of $F(X(\omega)\leq x| Y(\mu) = y)$ on all values of x, namely cumulative distribution of X assuming $Y(\mu)$ equals a fixed value of y.

Only by thinking this way, I can justify why $f_{x|y}(x|y)\equiv f(x|y) \equiv f_{x|y}(x)$. If my way of thinking is wrong, please interpret the different notation in the previous sentence and state why are they the same.

Also, $f_x(x)$ means exactly the same as $f_X(x)$, which is derivative of $F(X(\omega)\leq x)$.

Comment: yes they are the same, it is purely notation

Comment: I think you cannot really compare two experiments done on different sample spaces. You need X and Y to be random variables defined on the sample space $\Omega$ otherwise you cannot discuss their intercorrelation. For the notation I think they are equivalent.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Thanks! I guess I get paranoic too easily. Thanks for confirming!(also it would be great if you can have a look at my previous question:) )

Comment: @Thomas I think I roughly get what you mean, but intuitively I was thinking even if X and Y are on different sample space X can be conditioned on values of Y, depending on the underlying experiment. Are there any books or posts that I can study more about this?  Thanks :)